# Guest User is generating and inserting Blank PDF through VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, getcontentaspdf

Facing an issue when generating a PDF through the VF page from a Guest User but for the same code from the System Admin Profile, it's getting generated and inserted successfully.For the guest user, PDF is generated and inserted but while opening the PDF it is Blank.

Below is the code

```
            PageReference pageRef = Page.vfPageName;
            pageRef.getParameters().put('param', quoteId);
            Blob pdfbody=pageRef.getContentAsPDF();
            String fileName = 'Test';
            system.debug('pdfbody : '+pdfbody);
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
            cv.ContentLocation ='S';
            cv.Title = fileName;
            cv.PathOnClient = fileName +'.pdf';
            cv.VersionData = pdfbody;
            cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
            cv.SharingPrivacy = 'N';
            cv.firstPublishLocationId = quoteId;
            
            insert cv;
```

I am getting different blob sizes for both users.

All the Objects,field-level, VF Page, and Apex Classes permission are given to both users.

but still getting the issue.

Any Help is much appreciated

Comment: Could it be an access issue? Guest users have pretty limited access.

Comment: Yes, it seems like an access issue but I am not able to find that access ....like what access do I need to provide to that profile